# What's wrong with defining functions as rules?

Tags: functions, set-theory, foundations

From *Mathematical Proofs: A Transition to Advanced Mathematics* —

> Later in the 19th century, the German mathematician Richard Dedekind wrote:
>
> A function φ on a set S is a **law** according to which to every determinate element
> s of S there belongs a determinate thing which is called the transform of s and is
> denoted by φ(s).

Why can't we just use this intuitive definition of functions? Why do we define functions as sets of ordered pairs?

Let's consider two variables — $x$ and $y$. And let's say, $y = x + 2$. This equation *encodes* the notion of relations. It's a compact way of saying, "Two variable quantities $x$ and $y$ are related, such that $y$ is the sum of $x$ and $2$." In calculus, we call this relation/rule the function. But in *Set Theory*, functions are redefined as sets. But we know, the set

$$
F = \{(x, y) \in \Bbb R^2 : y = x + 2\}
$$

is the *extension* of the relation/rule, $y = x + 2$. Why then is it defined as the function itself. Here is another excerpt from *Elements of Set Theory* —

> The set of [ordered] pairs has at times been called the *graph* [extension] of the function; it is a subset of the coordinate plane $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R$. But the simplest procedure is to take this set of ordered pairs to **be** the function.

Why do the authors think, defining functions as sets is very natural? Why not just say, the set $F$ is the *extension* of the relation, implied by the equation $y = x + 2$, and the relation (intension) *is* the function?

Comment: because you would have to define what a "law" means

Comment: @AitorIribarLopez, Can I say, a function is a *description* of which elements in a given set corresponds to which unique elements in another set, possibly the same set? Can I say, functions are descriptions and the set of ordered pairs are the extensions of those descriptions?

Comment: Words like "law" and "description" would need to be defined.  To be clear:  it's fine to keep your intuitive notion in  mind, but formal proofs require formal definitions so you'll want something to fall back on.

Comment: Moreover, it probably depends on how you define _description_ but I'm pretty sure you wouldn't be able to _describe_ most real functions, because they don't "behave nicely". I don't even mean that finding a description would be hard, just that there'd probably not be enough possible descriptions for all of them.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's natural. I'd say it is a formal definition that captures the idea and lets you work with it capturing its properties. Also, I'd like to add that many people (like me) define the "law of correspondence" as **that** set of ordered pairs $F$. Then we define the function $f$ as the triple $(A,B,F)$, because our intuitive notion of function includes the information of what kind of values is takes and what kind of values it gives you back, or simply because we find it convenient.

Comment: The extensional definition makes it possible to say when two functions are equal, form the set of all functions between two sets, etc.